# Weka - Libsvm classes not in classpath

Tags: weka

So I am trying to use Libsvm in weka. I've tried what some answers said (I've added the path of the libsvm.jar file to the 'Path' windows variable, and I've check in the SystemInfo tab of Weka and the java.class.path does not contain the libsvm.jar), and I don't understand why since I added it to the path variable.
What can I do to try and fix it? Thanks

[image: Error that I get]

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the CLASSPATH environment variable  by creating a little startscript. java.exe takes a `-cp` argument that sets  CLASSPATH that java uses at startup.

So for Windows you could create a script/bat-file `weka-start.bat` with contents

```
rem change this to your setting:
WEKA_HOME=%USERPROFILE%/weka-3-9-4
WEKA_JAR=%USERPROFILE%/weka-3-9-4/weka.jar
CP="%WEKA_JAR%;%path_to_libsvm%/libsvm.jar"
rem assuming java.exe is in your %PATH%
java -cp %CP% -Xmx8092m weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

(untested, off the top of my head. I hope you get the idea.)

I'm a linux user, and my startscript looks like this. It also loads a few database drivers. Works for me…

```
#!/bin/bash
WEKA_HOME=/opt/smallapps/weka-stable/weka
export WEKA_JAR=$WEKA_HOME/weka.jar
export PATH=$WEKA_HOME:$PATH
CP="/usr/share/java/:/opt/dbvis9/jdbc/jtds/jtds.jar:/opt/database/sqlite/sqlite-jdbc.jar:$WEKA_JAR:/opt/smallapps/weka/wekafiles/packages/LibSVM/lib/libsvm.jar"
echo "used CLASSPATH: $CP"
DIR=/opt/smallapps/weka-stable/data/
echo "changing to '$DIR'"
cd "$DIR"
export WEKA_HOME=$DIR
# start small GUI Chooser
java -cp $CP -Xmx8092m weka.gui.GUIChooser 2>>/opt/smallapps/weka-stable/weka.log &
```